# Who are these feminists?

Tags: character-identification

The following image [surfaced in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/conversation/feminist-agenda).

[image: Six women, asking to be asked about their feminist agenda. From left to right, we see a white woman with brown hair, wearing a blue jacket and skirt; a white woman with long red hair, wearing an emerald dress; a Black woman, wearing a pale pink dress, her right hand thrust in the air, snapping her fingers; a white woman with long dark hair, wearing a black robe, holding a wand; a tanned white woman, wearing a blue, red, and gold "super hero outfit"; a white woman wearing long white robes]

Chatters were quick to identify the three women on the right: Hermione Granger, Wonder Woman, Princess Leia Organa.
The two women on the left took a bit more time, but they were identified as agent Carter and Merida of Dunbroch.

The last woman was identified as Princess Tiana of Maldonia, from the Disney film *The Princess and the Frog*.

However, I think this is incorrect, as she is depicted in simple robes, without a tiara. Also, Princess Tiana is never shown in a pink dress in the film.

**So who is she?**

Also, is the identification of the woman on the left as Sharon Carter correct?

Comment: The given answer is obviously correct but Tiana does wear a pink dress, just before she kisses the frog in the bedroom.

Comment: The comments on this post have veered off-topic into a discussion of feminism, so I've [moved the entire conversation to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52374/discussion-on-question-by-sqb-who-are-these-feminists). You can continue the discussion there as long as you wish, but please remember to [be nice](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) and respect each other's views. Further off-topic comments on this post will be removed, since mods can't move new comments to chat after the room has been created.

Comment: Peggy = Sharon?

Comment: Wonder Woman is awesome, that is all.

Comment: Worth noting that Angelica Schuyler was a real person of Dutch decent, but this portrays the character from Hamilton and not the historical figure.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

[Culturess.com](https://culturess.com/2016/11/25/geeky-gift-guide-get-every-geek-list/7/) (referencing the official reseller of T-Shirts and branded accessories from the picture's creator) identifies the models as follows;

> That is why this “Feminist Agenda” print by [Karen Hallion](https://khallion.deviantart.com/art/Feminist-Agenda-644861877) is the
> perfect gift for geeky feminist or even the young feminist in
> training. It features some of pop culture’s best role models: **Peggy
> Carter** from Agent Carter, **Merida** from Brave, **Angelica Schuyler** from
> Hamilton, **Hermione Granger** from Harry Potter, **Wonder Woman**, and
> **Princess (now General) Leia** from Star Wars. It is a powerful image of
> sisterhood and strength.

As you can see from the composite below, these are all people that Karen Hallion has drawn before.

[image]

---

[image]

The bird [sitting on the text](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/208201/20774) appears to be in reference to the picture and story that Hallion cites as being the inspiration for her artwork;

> *"Inspired by Chelsea Cain and the Mockingbird".*
>
> <sub><sup>[Feminist Agenda by khallion via Instagram](https://www.deviantart.com/khallion/art/Feminist-Agenda-644861877)</sup></sub>

[image]
<sub><sup>[Chelsea Cain: Mockingbird writer receives support after cover backlash](https://ew.com/article/2016/10/26/chelsea-cain-mockingbird-feminist-backlash/)</sup></sub>

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52364/discussion-on-answer-by-valorum-who-are-these-feminists).

Comment: @WhyBird.jpg - I've included some additional info about the bird (and the inspiration behind the art).

Answer (score 65):

## [Angelica Schuyler Church](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angelica_Schuyler_Church) [(Renée Elise Goldsberry)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ren%C3%A9e_Elise_Goldsberry)

Angelica Schuyler is a character from the Musical *"Hamilton"*. She's portrayed by Renée Elise Goldsberry and wears a pink dress, as pictured below:

Angelica Shuyler is also quoted as saying:

> "'We hold these truths to be self-evident
> That all men are created equal'
> And when I meet Thomas Jefferson
> I'mma compel him to put women in the sequel"

Which reflects on her "feminist agenda"

[image]

Another image (a cartoonisation of the one above), by the same artist can be found [here](https://khallion.deviantart.com/art/Revelation-598805961)

## Not Sharon but [Peggy Carter](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Peggy_Carter)

I also believe the person on the far left is Peggy Carter (looks like Hayley Atwell's portrayal of her):

[image]

Comment: add [this one](http://img05.deviantart.net/d3fd/i/2016/004/3/b/disney_princess_merida_brave_by_theringofbelief-d8a8me9.jpg), and IMO you're set ^_^

Comment: @reirab yep sorry